# How can I get the coordinates of polygons drawn in Google Maps-My Maps?

Tags: polygon, google-maps, coordinates

I have a custom Google Maps using My Maps which has some polygons (around 18) and I would like to get the coordinates of each polygon without having to place markers on every corner.

This is an example of the polygons I want to get the coordinates. I only want the coordinates of the vertices or the corners, not what is inside. [image: polygon sample]

Is this possible? How I can achieve this?

Comment: Use "Export to KML", open the exported file in some text editor and you will see the coordinates.

Comment: Omg, you are right! I need to parse this. Does Beautiful Soup works for this? or any other recommeded way?

Comment: http://geospatialconversions.azurewebsites.net ?

Comment: Thank you, Anatoly! :D Btw, just noticed that the latitude and longitude are "reversed". Like, the original coordinate should be `(lat,long)` and the coordinate in the .kml file appears like `(long,lat,0)`. Is this normal? What is this `0`?

Comment: Yes, the order in kml is longitude, latitude, altitude. 0 is altitude.

Comment: Thank you Anatoly. Please, put all this as an answer, so I can click it as accepted answer :)

Comment: You're welcome. Sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can export your layers to kml following [these](https://support.google.com/mymaps/answer/3109452?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) instructions.
2. You can open the exported file in a text editor or you can convert it to WKT using a tool like [this](http://geospatialconversions.azurewebsites.net/).